# Converting String from SerialPort, converring to byte array, then being able to identify each byte individually

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a byte array coming in through the SerialPort of gto 8 bytes. Each byte within the array means something different so I am looking for a wy to be able to label each byte to be interrogated later on in the program. I know the code below is not right, but I need to be able to interrogate each byte from byte0 up to byte7.

For example:

```
        rxString = mySerialPort.ReadExisting();
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rxString);

        if (bytes.SequenceEqual(new byte[] { (byte0) = 0x95 }))

        {
            tb_Status.AppendText("Correct Sequence");
        }

        else 

        {
            tb_Status.AppendText("Incorrect Sequence!!!");
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: You mean `bytes[0]` to `bytes[7]` ?

Comment: Reading bytes is the job of the [Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143549(v=vs.110).aspx) method, not ReadExisting. To read the value of a byte you use an index, ie `bytes[0]`

Comment: Can you give an example please?

Comment: To get byte nbr. 4: `var x = bytes[3];` (0-indexed so 4th byte is index 3)

Comment: Each byte received needs to be interrogated at some point in the software, so don't I need to use the ReadExisting to ensure I get all the bytes out the buffer? Do I use the Read method something like this             "rxString = mySerialPort.Read(new byte[0], new byte[1], new byte[2], new byte[3], etc...)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply read the bytes into an array and access them by an index (0 to 7 as you said). If you interpret a special meaning on specific bytes, you should encapsulate the whole thing in a class and provide a named access to the array by properties like:

```
public short MyFancyData {
  get {
    return bytes[2] + (bytes[3] << 8);
  }
}

public byte MyLessFancyData {
  get {
    return bytes[7];
  }
}

public bool IsCorrect {
  get {
    return bytes[0] == 0x95;
  }
}
// etc.
```

Comment: Yeah, this works Great.... However I am not sure if this is related, I will start another thread otherwise, but for some weird reason byte[5] always reads 0x63, all the other bytes read what they are sent. (I have checked this on a scope, I have 0xE5 coming in, but the software reads it as 0x63).

Comment: This has definitely nothing to do with the problem asked here. If you didn't accidentally assign a value instead of checking for equality (`=` vs. `==`) you might have another problem with reading the input. I don't know.

Comment: I have gone through the code, I defiantly do not mistake = and == anywhere... it seems very strange. I will start a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

Is this getting close?

```
        rxString = SerialPort.ReadExisting();
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rxString);
        var a = bytes[0];
        var b = bytes[1];

        if (a == 0x74)

        {
            tb_Status.AppendText("This is Good");
        }
```